# Can we display how long launched sites were in beta on their Area 51 proposals?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

When evaluating how well a given Area 51 site in public beta is doing, it's helpful to compare to other Area 51 sites that have launched. I think a useful metric to see would be *how long* each site that has now launched was in beta for prior to launch. This should be trivial to add:

[image: Proposed screenshot with FHC FTW]

This would be a very useful metric to see, I think.

Comment: I like how the screenshot depicts the UX proposal.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I suggested it because one of my site's users lamented UX being in beta for *way too long*, and I don't want my site to be in beta nearly that long

Comment: IT does show "private beta start" but it's only accurate to the year in this case, missing like 40% of the time the site was in beta.

Comment: @BenBrocka Well, it does have a datestamp tooltip like other times on the site (although the launched date is lacking said tooltip)

Comment: @TimStone if I have to do math, the unicorn will not eat the waffle!

Comment: It is well established that unicorns do not enjoy math.

Comment: So since it didn't get 10 upvotes and I answered the question does that mean [I get to eat the Unicorn instead](http://www.thinkgeek.com/caffeine/wacky-edibles/e5a7/)?

Comment: @Josh'sSocks the question now has 10 upvotes thanks to your answer! So I'm going to update the picture with the unicorn eating *you*

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I was a bit too quick to criticize you before. The Area 51 page doesn't contain the date the site launched... but my friend Tim Stone reminded me that the API *does* provide this information. So I continue to assert that you being **a JavaScript developer *as your primary profession* and still needing to ask the community to do this for you** means you're totally pathetic.

**I updated my code**, it now uses the API to fetch the site's launch date and then adds a "public beta duration" heading to the Area51 page. I've made it [available as a userscript](http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/SoTimeMahBetas.user.js) and [The Unhandled Exception listed it on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3127). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Now accurate!]

Here's the code to do this:

```
var mySiteInfoUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/info?filter=!)5788xVOwy(eXAQATQD*PIQMmK-z&callback=SoTimeMahBetaSiteInfoCallback&site=';

window.SoTimeMahBetaSiteInfoCallback = function SoTimeMahBetaSiteInfoCallback(data) {
    //console.log("SoTimeMahBetaSiteInfoCallback got ",data);
    var publicBetaStart = publicBetaStartLabel.next().find("span").attr('title');
    var publicBetaStartDate = new Date(publicBetaStart);

    if(data.items[0] && data.items[0].site.launch_date) {
        var siteLaunchDate = new Date(1970,0,1);
        siteLaunchDate.setSeconds(parseInt(data.items[0].site.launch_date));

        var publicBetaDuration = (siteLaunchDate - publicBetaStartDate)/1000;

        publicBetaStartLabel.before('<p class="label-key">public beta duration</p><p class="label-value">'+secondsToDuration(publicBetaDuration)+'</p>');
    }
}

function getSiteInfo(site) {
    $(document.head).append('<script src="'+mySiteInfoUrl+site+'"></script>');
}

/**
 * Converts seconds to an english date ("3 days, 4 hours, 5 minuts, 6 seconds")
 *
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/818945/75801
 **/
function secondsToDuration(seconds) {
    var tbl = [
        [ 365*24*60*60, 'year' ],
        [ 7*24*60*60, 'week' ],
        [ 24*60*60, 'day' ],
        [ 60*60, 'hour' ],
        [ 60, 'minute' ],
        [ 1, 'second' ]
    ];

    var t = parseInt(seconds), r = '', tblLength = tbl.length, i, u;

    for (i = 0; i < tblLength; i++) {
        var d = tbl[i];
        if (d[0] < t) {
            u = Math.floor(t / d[0]);
            t -= u * d[0];
            r += u + ' ' + d[1] + (u == 1 ? ' ' : 's ');
        }
    }

    return r;
}

var publicBetaStartLabel = $('p.label-key:contains(public beta start)');
if(publicBetaStartLabel.length) {
    var vistSiteNowLink = $('a.site-health-visit-link');

    if(vistSiteNowLink.length) {
        var siteName = vistSiteNowLink.attr('href').match(/http:\/\/([A-Za-z]+)\..*/)[1];
        getSiteInfo(siteName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to [This StackOverflow answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122355/151695), otherwise it would have taken me 3.2 minutes.

Comment: -1 no microsecond count. :P

Comment: -1 **This is not the length of the private beta** you stupid, stupid sock! This is *how long ago the beta started*. You need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: tsk tsk, having arguments with yourself

Comment: He's about to be washed again @jcolebrand